# How write file in maven resource?

Tags: maven, resources, java-io

I know how to read a file from maven resource, usually the following way can be used:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/XXX.txt");
```

It seems it only can be read?
But I want to write content into it, how can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to write in `resources`?

Comment: such as appent datetime,but it seems write in memory not the  txt file

Comment: no special reason~I just want know how to write~ Or no way to write?just can be read?

Comment: do you want to have the build time in the resource file? Then have a look at this page http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html

Comment: the .getResourceAsStream loads resources from the classpath, which is typically inside a jar - therefore it is read-only. You can always create a new File in src/main/resources and write to it. Just be aware you run the build in the correct folder.

Comment: @wemu thanks,but if the file is the propertites,it  can`t write either?

Comment: if the .properties file is inside a jar then no. But if you put that file in a known folder you will be able to write into it (like: new File("./src/main/resources/my.properties") and then with an outputstream). If you want to add some maven variables you may better use resource filtering: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html (to write the version in a properties file for ex)

Comment: @wemu thanks! it does work~thank you very much